# PHP/MySQL Delete User - Function

Tags: php, mysql, forms, function

I am trying to understand the work with functions a little bit more so I decided to write a few functions for my PHP script. Well the first function is not working and I want to understand why to avoid those issues in the future.

Here is what I did:
I just wanted to create a function to delete an admin inside the database. Here is my code:

```
<?php
// Delete Mitarbeiter
  function deleteMitarbeiter($id) {
        if(!isset($id) || !is_int($id)) { 
            return FALSE; // wrong parameters, return early
        }
        $deleteUser = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM `admin` WHERE id=?");
        $deleteUser->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        return $deleteUser->execute(); // returns true on success, otherwise false
    }

if (isset ($_POST['deletemitarbeiter'])) {
    $member_Id =  $_POST['member_Id'];
    deleteMitarbeiter($member_Id);
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="edit_mitarbeiter.php" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result_member_ID;?>" name="member_Id">
<button type="submit" name="deletemitarbeiter" value="deletemitarbeiter" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg pull-right">Mitarbeiter löschen</button>
</form>
```

I do have error_reporting on but I do not get any errors. I guess there is something wrong with my parameter? I really stuck on this.

EDIT:
Here is my edited code:

```
<?php
// Delete Mitarbeiter
  function deleteMitarbeiter($id) {
        if(!isset($id) || !is_int($id)) {
            return FALSE; // wrong parameters, return early
        }
        try {
        $db = new DbContext();
        $deleteUser = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `admin` WHERE id=?");
        $deleteUser->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        return $deleteUser->execute(); // returns true on success, otherwise false
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Could not execute the delete: " . $e->getMessage());
}}

if (isset ($_POST['deletemitarbeiter'])) {
    $member_Id = intval($_POST['member_Id']);
    deleteMitarbeiter($member_Id);
}
?>
```

Now my error message is: `Fatal error: Class 'DbContext' not found`! What should my code look like?

Comment: I think the problem is the passed parameter with the method post. Normally every submitted values are strings and you have to convert them back to int if you use them there. Try `$member_Id = intval($_POST['member_Id'])`

Comment: Where in your function are you telling it to die on error and output that error to the browser? I don't see it. Something like `catch (PDOException $e) {
 die("Could not execute the delete: " . $e->getMessage());
}` after `return $deleteUser->execute(); // returns true on success, otherwise false
    }`

Comment: @RaphaelMüller I used your code and now I get the following error message:  'Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in'

Comment: @ChristophC. `$this` is only available if your method is in a class. since your method is a free function, you can't access `$this` there. you have to instantiate your database class, i.e. do something like this: `$db = new DbContext(); $db->prepare...`

Comment: @RaphaelMüller I edited my first post and posted my current code. Now the error message is: Fatal error: Class 'DbContext' not found ! I am doing something wrong. What does my code need to look like?

Comment: @ChristophC. `DbContext()` was just an example. In your first post, you use `$this` where does this come from?

Comment: I guess from nowhere! But I do not know how I sould edit my function or what my function should look like so that it works

Comment: @ChristophC. ok, hold on a sec, i'll make a basic example as answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88683/discussion-between-raphael-muller-and-christoph-c).

Comment: @ChristophC. please see my answer. and if there are some questions don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` returns an string. So `is_int($id)` is false and the method doesn't execute.

Do escaping inside the method to solve this.

**UPDATE**

`is_int` function checks the real type, and if you pass an string, returns false, even the string is numeric. You can use `is_numeric()` instead, to check numeric strings.

Comment: I edited my code in my first post and removed the escape string but it is still not working. What should my method look like?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going in the right direction.

Hope this helps.

**EDITED**

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; $db = 'database-name'; $user = 'database-user'; $pw = 'database-password';
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8', $user, $pw);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Delete Mitarbeiter
  function deleteMitarbeiter($id) {
        if(!isset($id) || !is_int($id)) { 
            return FALSE; // wrong parameters, return early
        }
        try {
        $id = $_POST['member_Id']; // this is the line I added
        $sql = "DELETE FROM `admin` WHERE id=?";
        $deleteUser = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $deleteUser->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        return $deleteUser->execute(); // returns true on success, otherwise false
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Could not execute the delete: " . $e->getMessage());
}}

if (isset ($_POST['deletemitarbeiter'])) {
    $member_Id =  $_POST['member_Id'];
    deleteMitarbeiter($member_Id);
}
?>
```

Comment: That is not my problem but thanks! I do get errors instead of blank page.

Comment: @Kuya why do you catch the error and then die nevertheless? you should do proper error handling there...

Comment: @RaphaelMüller Why would you want the script to continue to run if you have already encountered an error?

Comment: @Kuya if you don't catch the error, it breaks anyway ;)

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working. Still get no error message (even with error reporting on) but the user is not deleted from database.

Comment: Add this line directly underneath try { `$id = $_POST['member_Id']; // this is the line I added` 

See the updated answer

Comment: @ChristophC. - Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).
Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

let's dig into some basics. why you can't use $this inside of a free function:

```
<?php

//our base class
class Test
{
    private $privateVar = 0;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        //access $this from within this class Test
        $this->privateVar = $value;
    }

    public function DoSomething()
    {
        //access $this from within this class Test with the initialized value from the constructor
        echo $this->privateVar;
    }

    public static function DoSomeStatic()
    {
        //since this is a static method you can't access $this here...
        echo "some static";
    }
}

//your function here
function testFunction()
{
    $test = new Test(1233);
    $test->DoSomething();

    $test2 = new Test(456677);
    $test2->DoSomething();

    Test::DoSomeStatic();

    //and you can't access $this here also, since $this is the context of the class.
    //i.e. if you aren't in a class there exists no object $this and therefor you can't call $this->DoSomething() here.
}

//and call your testfunction
testFunction();
```

since your method `deleteMitarbeiter` is a free function (does not exist in a class context) there is no `$this` object. so, you have to make an instance of your object or use a static method.

BTW: I would also consider to use only english words while programming and not german ones...

now to your problem:

you want to use your database context in this free function:

```
//i suppose your db context looks something like this:
class DbContext
{
    private $db = NULL;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    }
}
```

so you wan't to access $db outside of this class. you have to modify it, or do some proxiing.

if you go for a proxy, extend your class with something like this:

```
public function execute()
{
    $this->db->execute();
}
```

and you can make an instance of your context in your method `deleteMitarbeiter` like this:

```
function deleteMitarbeiter($id)
{
   $context = new DbContext();
   $context->execute();
}
```

but if you choose to use `DbContext` as your base class you can extend your class where all the operations of your "Mitarbeiter" or "co-workers" are happening.

```
class DbContext
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new PDO...
    }
}

class CoWorkerController extends DbContext
{
     function delete($id)
     {
        $this->db->execute();
     }
}
```